# How do I change the width of the combobox button?

Tags: c#, winforms

My combobox allows typing into the text portion so the only way to get the dropdown list is to click the button. However, since this will be used on touchscreen devices, it is hard to click it when it is this 'thin'.

Is there any way to increase the width of the combobox button?

[image]

Comment: i would place a  button over combo box's  button , then do Expand list on button click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative to resizing the button would be to set the `DroppedDown` property to `true` inside the `Click` event. This will show the drop down list when the user clicks inside the edit area of the `ComboBox`, effectively extending the button area to the whole control:

```
private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround. Another alternative if the OP wants to limit the area which triggers the dropdown would be to use the `MouseClick` event instead and do something like `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.X > comboBox1.Width - 30) comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize dropdown button (the size of the arrow and the size of the button are completely in our control), there is a class called `Combo​Box​Renderer`.

Here you have complete example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.comboboxrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2

It is supported from .Net2.0.

You should create a custom `ComboBox` control and call `DrawDropDownButton` of the `comboboxrenderer` in the paint event.

In the above link(example) `arrowSize` and `arrowRectangle` are two variables which helps in deciding your dropdown button size, along with below static function (of `ComboBoxRenderer`) call in overridden paint event.

```
ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, arrowRectangle,arrowState);
```

Comment: That could be a good approach _if you're willing to invest some time into creating a custom ComboBox_, as almost every feature of the ComboBox control (items, auto-complete, data binding, etc.) will need to be re-implemented from scratch.

Comment: Yes @AhmedAbdelhameed there is complexity involved. But databindings is System.Windows.Forms.control class property. The custom control is derived from control. And most of the properties are available with the control class.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the `DataBindings` property. I meant binding data using a `DataSource`.

Comment: Like @AhmedAbdelhameed said there is work involved in implementation from scratch. But if someone wants to see source code of combobox implementation refer https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ComboBox.cs